# Mostrar imagen en ventana Tkinter alojada en web

Tags: python, tkinter, web, imagen

Muy buenas, estoy buscando informacion y no encuentro nada, necesito mostrar una imagen alojada en una web desde una ventana en tkinter. Pero no encuentro ninguna informacion al respecto, si me pueden ayudar seguro que es facil pero de verdad que ya lo he probado todo sin resultados.
Pd: Os dejo una de las muchas pruebas que he realizado para que veais la idea que me gustaria realizar:
Muchas gracias de antemano

```
import tkinter
import webbrowser

imagenAnchuraMaxima=300
imagenAlturaMaxima=200


img = webbrowser.open('http://old.arasaac.org/classes/img/thumbnail.php?i=c2l6ZT0yMDAmcnV0YT0uLi8uLi9yZXBvc2l0b3Jpby9vcmlnaW5hbGVzLzU0NDEucG5n')

root = tkinter.Tk()

root.title("Mostrar imagen")

tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

label= Label(root, image=tkimage, width=imagenAnchuraMaxima, height=imagenAlturaMaxima).pack()

buttonStart2= Button(root, text="Cerrar",command=root.quit).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a [es.so], te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. ¿Qué has intentado hacer hasta el momento? Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que los usuarios publiquen sus preguntas junto con lo que han intentado, de esa forma se demuestra que has hecho un esfuerzo por resolver tu pregunta/problema, de lo contrario probablemente la pregunta termine cerrada y/o votada negativamente. Lectura recomendada: [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Por muy fácil que parezca o muy tonto que crear que es, al colocar parte de tu código es de gran ayuda para ver que has INTENTADO por tu cuenta y que estas haciendo mal para así poder darte una correcta solución en caso de que exista!.  Puedes darle [edit] a tu pregunta y agregar tu código sin problema alguno!

Comment: @Dani-Pous si sos el mismo usuario que redactó la pregunta, solicitá [combinar los perfiles de usuario](/contact).